# Вычислительный кластер на Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, распараллеливание, кластер

Возможно ли создать что-то вроде вычислительного кластера, используя Android смартфоны? Т.е. по сути нужно объединить несколько смартфонов в одну сеть и заставить решать одну вычислительную задачу, при этом распараллелив её как между ядрами смартфона, так и между самими смартфонами. Есть ли какие-нибудь решения в этой сфере и как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Почему не компьютеры?

Comment: Можно, разумеется. Это ж, по сути, компьютеры. Причём имеющие доступ к интернету, как правило. Остаётся, собственно, написать параллелящуюся задачу и по сети раздавать задания отдельным узлам. В чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что хотелось узнать какие есть решения в данной области. На пример программные интерфейсы для обмена и тд.